# How to store cart items in localStorage and display that item using AJAX in Spring Boot?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I am working on an online shopping spring boot web application. I have a **ADD TO CART** functionality. So, I just tried to implement it using **localStorage**. But there are some storage restriction, items can not be added beyond 3 or 5 MB. Below is my script to add items to cart. I want implement add to cart feature for both guest user as well as registered user. I mean, that when a guest user visit my web app and wants to add some items to his/her cart and when try to buy or checkout then after successful login he/she would be able to view his/her cart items that has been added previously. So I want to add this feature in both cases. But after so many research work, I did not find a better and esay way to do so. Whether should I go for localStorage or HttpSession. By choosing any of the mechanism, how to do this thing. **Please help me. I am stuck at this part for couple of weeks.** Do I need to call AJAX function for add to cart button?

**In the below code, when there is no items in cart then block is executing as expected. But if I have already some item present inside my cart then how should I do this?**

```
function addtocart(pid,pname){
        var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
        var price = $("#pprice").text();
        var pprice = price.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
        var cart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
        if(cart == null) { 
            /* No item in cart. Cart is not created yet */
            var products = [];
            var product = {productid : pid ,productname : pname ,pprice : pprice ,quantity : quantity};
            products.push(product);
            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(products));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(products));
            console.log("Product is added for the first time");
            
        }else {
            // item in cart is already present
            var pcart = [JSON.stringify(cart)];
            var oldproduct = pcart.find(item => item.productid == pid);
            var product = {productid : pid, productname : pname, pprice : pprice, quantity : quantity};
            pcart.push(product);
            localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(pcart));
            console.log("Product is added again");
        }
           updatecart();
    }
```

Below script is to update count of items present in cart.

```
function updatecart(){
            var cartstring = localStorage.getItem("cart");
            console.log(JSON.parse(cartstring));
            var cart = JSON.parse(cartstring);
            console.log(cart.pprice);
            var cartlength = cart.length;
            if(cart == null || cart.length == 0){
                console.log("Cart is empty!!!!");
                $(".add_cart_wrap").html('0');
            }else{
                // there is some item in the cart
                console.log(cart);
                $(".add_cart_wrap").html(cartlength);
            }
        }
```

[image: Screenshot to display entire scenario]

Comment: Hi, so you are facing problem in else condition ?

Comment: @Swati Yes, when product is already present in basket or cart then I am facing problem. Because it should update cart. But failed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `pid` is already present in localStorage or not . Then , if not present you can get the whole json object and then update the quantity value and save this new updated values in *localStorage* .

***Updated Code*** :

```
function addtocart(pid, pname) {
  var quantity = $("#quantity").val() != "" ? parseInt($("#quantity").val()) : 0;
  var price = $("#pprice").text();
  var pprice = price.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
  var cart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
  var pcart = JSON.parse(cart) != null ? JSON.parse(cart) : [];
  //get index of the json array where the productid is there ...
  var present_or_not = pcart.findIndex(item => item.productid == pid);
  //if the item not presnt , is null
  if (cart == null || present_or_not == null || present_or_not == -1) {
    var product = {
      productid: pid,
      productname: pname,
      pprice: pprice,
      quantity: quantity
    };
    pcart.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(pcart));

  } else {
    //get the the json from index...
    var actual_stored_product = pcart[present_or_not];
    pcart.splice(present_or_not, 1); //remove the json array 
    //get the qty which was already prsnt
    var actual_qty = actual_stored_product.quantity == null || actual_stored_product.quantity == "" ? 0 : actual_stored_product.quantity;
    //update the value
    actual_stored_product.quantity = parseInt(actual_qty) + quantity;
    //now..we have updated value..push obj again..
    pcart.push(actual_stored_product);
    //store the json in local Storage
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(pcart));
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(pcart));
   updatecart();
}
```

Comment: Do you think localStorage is good approach to store guest user cart items in basket? Is there any other alternative. Like, without logged in user can add items in cart and when he/she logged in then previously added items would be visible too.

Comment: I got JSON data above.
[
   {
      "productid":"15",
      "productname":"Couple Poster Cake",
      "pprice":"1614",
      "quantity":2
   },
   {
      "productid":"14",
      "productname":"Chocolate Truffle Cake",
      "pprice":"664",
      "quantity":2
   },
   {
      "productid":"14",
      "productname":"Chocolate Truffle Cake",
      "pprice":"1328",
      "quantity":4
   }
]

Comment: Hi , its not working on your end ? Did you check what `present_or_not` has ?

Comment: I want to ask that Is localStorage good for when guest user login and would be able to see items in his cart that has been added when he visited the we app and added some items in cart?

Comment: That depends on you  or you can just store some random unique id inside localStorage for particular user and then whatever that user select(products) you can store those product in your db with that unique id so , whenever that user again visit your website you can check if there is unique_id in localStorage or not depending that you can fetch the data from db and show in frontend.

Comment: and then user decide to sign up you can use that localStorage id to get all product which he/she has choosen earlier and store them with the register user id .

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: No problem , Glad to help :)